# How do I execute an update query in Zend 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying not to use the function execute(), I'm trying to execute an update query in this way:

```
public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
}

public function getUserProfile($array_post) {
    $data = array(
        'username' => $array_post['username'],
        'email' => $array_post['mail']
    );

    $where = $this->adapter->quoteInto('id = ?', $array_post['userid']);

    $this->update($data, $where);
}
```

But I do not know what is it the equivalent function of this **quoteInto()** in ZEND 2. Now i getting a blank page, when it is executed, no errors, nothing . Can you help me with this method ? thx

**UPDATE** I tried also this way:

```
$data = array(
    'username' => $array_post['username'],
    'email' => $array_post['mail']
);

$update = $this->adapter->update();
$update = $update->set($data);
$update->where(array('id' => $array_post['userid']));
```

Comment: What exactly is the adapter in the second example? You can get this with `get_class($adapter);`

Comment: the adapter is called in the constructor

Comment: Sorry, i was looking for the full qualified name to make sure you were not using some custom adapter. Hopefully my answer below will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example using the `TableGateway` mentioned by ForrestLyman.

```
public function updateAction($data)
         {
             $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
             $sql = new Sql($adapter);
             $update = $sql->update();
             $update->table('table_name');
             $update->set($data);
             $update->where('action_id = '.$data['action_id'].'');

             $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($update);
             $result = $statement->execute();

             $flag = $result->getAffectedRows();
             if(!($flag)){
                     return false;
             }else{
                     return true;
             }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Databases work quite a bit differently in Zend 2 compared to Zend 1. The adapter is a very lightweight object, and does not include any CRUD methods. You need to use the TableGateway if you want to use these methods.

Alternatively you can create a SQL object, then execute it with the adapter.

I created a very minimal active record implementation (that works a lot like Zend 1 tables) to make it a little simpler. Here's a link if you want to check it out: https://github.com/forrestLyman/ZendActiveRecord